# APK of react-native app shows blank screen

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

I have built a react-native app which works perfectly fine in development, but when I generate the APK with `expo build:android`, it doesn't work. If I load the app on my android device, the splash screen is displayed for a few moments and then it just shows a blank screen. I am unsure how to check what the error is when using the apk. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be with the SDK version. Check your device API level and the SDK version your building with.

You could set up a [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) (Android Debug Bridge) and install the apk onto a device/emulator. There you have a number of options for debugging.

**Edit:**

If there isn't any android specific code that uses the API then you can ignore what I said before.

1. Uninstall the app on your device. Settings > Apps > [Your App] > Uninstall
2. In your development run 'expo start'
3. If dev is working, then run 'expo start --no-dev --minify'
4. If that works then you can build 'expo build:android'
5. Install apk on your device || with ADB preferably

Information need for further troubleshooting:-

- Device Version [Found on device Settings>System>About]
- Expo SDK [Found in app.json]
- ADB logs

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this, so could you expand a bit about api level and sdk version please